# How to group the Continuous variable by Bining in R

Tags: r, statistics

Let say we have two column C1 and C2 both are Continuous Variable , and our task is "we have to group the C1 column by seq(3,13.5,0.5) and depending on the no of points coming in every Bin we have to some the Data points of C2 Respectively "[image]

Comment: What is the intention with C2? "To some the Data" does not make sense. It appears be be a typo for "to sum the data", but summing data from another variable will not increase the number of points.

Comment: @Bernhard grouping should be as per binning Column should be Group with seq(3,13.5,0.5) And the number of Points has to summed from other column(C2)

Comment: I am sorry. I have answered the fist half but the second half I do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To group column C1 by the given breakpoints, there ist the `cut`command in R:

```
C <- data.frame(C1=runif(30))
C$group <- cut(C$C1, c(0, .2, .4, .6, .8, 1))
print(C)
```

The number of points in every group/bin can be displayed using `table`:

```
table(C$group)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m<- seq(3,13.5,0.5)
C$bin_grouping <- cut(C$C1,m) 
#Once i have Bin_grouping further i Used Dplyr Package as such to sum C2 Column
by_bin<-group_by(C,bin_grouping)
new_C <-summarise(by_bin,new_C2=sum(C2, na.rm = TRUE),Count=n())
```